# Hook not accept to get ref from custom component?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

For example, i want to get ref in message component:
Main.js:

```
import * as React from "react"
export const Main: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = observer((props) => {
  const ref = React.useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ///Can not get ref from message
    ref.current.gotoPosition(5)
  }, [])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Message
        ref={ref}
        />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Message.js:

```
import * as React from "react"
// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
export const Message = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ({
  const { ... } = props

  const gotoPosition = (index) => {
    console.log('in here')
  }
  return (
    <View>
....
</View>
  )
}
)
```

I can not get ref from Message, even i used React.forwardRef. How to access gotoPosition function in Message by ref like ref.gotoPosition(5). Thanks

Comment: I think you need to use ref.current.gotoPosition().  What do you get if you console.log(ref).

Comment: sorry, i edit post, i use current but the same, can not get anything

Comment: use ref inside Message.js

Comment: if i want to use ref in main.js, how can i do?